# OpenCV: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0)

Tags: c++, opencv

По совету одного из участников создавал оптический поток, но не очень удачно.

Ошибка в рантайме

```
Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0)
```

говорит, что у меня что-то не так с третьим параметром `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, а именно `InputArray prevPts`, который является вектором 2D-точек, по которому и будет строиться оптический поток. В англоязычном интернете есть целый набор таких же вопросов, но ответы, кажется, зависели от конкретной ситуации.

Вот мой упрощённый код:

```
// создание cv::Mat объекта, вырезанного из кадра
// через прямоугольник cv::Rect collection
auto object = (*frame)(collection);

// конвертация в одноканальное изображение
cvtColor(object, object, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// создание векторов
std::vector<cv::Point2f> prev_points;  // станет *points.first
std::vector<cv::Mat> prev_pyr;         // станет *pyramids.first

// заполнение векторов
goodFeaturesToTrack(object, prev_points, 200, 0.01, 0.1);
buildOpticalFlowPyramid(object, prev_pyr, cv::Size(21, 21), 5);

// кидаем векторы в std::map, луковично выглядит, конечно
points_pyramids.insert(
    make_pair
    (
        make_pair   // потом будет прочтено как optical_flow.first
        (
            make_pair(&prev_points, nullptr),   // optical_flow.first.first
            make_pair(&prev_pyr, nullptr)       // optical_flow.first.second
        ),
        std::make_pair(nullptr, nullptr)        // optical_flow.second
    )
);
```

В другом же методе работаем с потоком:

```
// достаём из std::map, optical_flow - одно из его значений
auto points = optical_flow.first.first;
auto pyramids = optical_flow.first.second;
auto stats = optical_flow.second;

// убираем пустые ссылки
if (points.second == nullptr)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> next_points;
    points.second = &next_points;
}
if (pyramids.second == nullptr)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> next_pyramids;
    // находим пирамиды для нового кадра
    buildOpticalFlowPyramid(*gray, next_pyramids, cv::Size(21, 21), 5);
    pyramids.second = &next_pyramids;
}
if (stats.first == nullptr)
{
    std::vector<uchar> status;
    stats.first = &status;
}
if (stats.second == nullptr)
{
    std::vector<float> err;
    stats.second = &err;
}

// Сам метод Лукаса-Канаде в OpenCV, и здесь происходит ошибка
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(*pyramids.first, *pyramids.second,
        *points.first, *points.second, *stats.first, *stats.second);
```

Пояснения:

- `*pyramids.first` - пирамиды, построенные конкретно по исходному объекту;
- `*pyramids.second` - здесь лежат пирамиды, построенные по цельному новому кадру;
- `*points.first` - тут находятся локальные 2D-точки, особые для объекта;
- `*points.second` - сюда будут добавлены те же 2D-точки, найденные на новом кадре;
- `*stats.first` - `status`, указывающий, есть неопределённое поведение или нет;
- `*stats.second` - `error`, что-то в роде среднеквадратичного отклонения.

Напомню, что ошибка возникает из-за третьего параметра, и это `*points.first`. Значения в него добавлены через `goodFeaturesToTrack(object, prev_points, 200, 0.01, 0.1);`.

Comment: Призываю сюда @alexis031182 !

Comment: Попробуйте добавить проверку сразу после `goodFeaturesToTrack()` на количество обнаруженных точек. Если их вообще не было найдено, то надо либо заново запустить функцию с более щадящими параметрами, либо перейти к следующему кадру, минуя код, вычисляющий оптический поток.

Comment: @alexis031182 , вы не знаете, каковы более-менее оптимальные параметры для этого? Знаю только это: чем больше найденных точек, тем с большей вероятностью определен нужный объект, но тем больше нужно времени для этого. А вот для `qualityLevel` и `minDistance` я никаких почти более-менее универсальных рекомендаций не нашёл.

Comment: Да, чем больше точек, тем больше вероятность, что получите корректную позицию объекта от кадра к кадру, но, разумеется, это ведёт к большей вычислительной нагрузке. Впрочем, всё равно не такой высокой, как у Фарнебека. Что касаемо остальных параметров, то тут сложно дать рекомендации, т.к. эти параметры зависят от того, что наличествует в кадре. Я обычно поступал так: создавал в настройках программы всякие ползунки и предоставлял пользователю возможность подстравивать параметры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял ошибку. Дело не в параметрах, а том, что я пытался использовать вектор из другого метода, когда как деструктор первого метода очищал этот вектор, и `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` читал два пустых исходника - тот, который должен был быть с точками, и тот, который с пирамидами.

Пришлось использовать динамический вектор.

Также следовало пирамиды строить не по объекту, а тому кадру, где объект был найден.